# Can you help me rephrase this sentence?

Tags: american-english

> An immersive photo-driven experience of the beauty of XXX's motorcycle design supported by real riders stories.

I'm not convinced of `the beauty of XXX's motorcycle design`

what I'm trying to say that an immersive experience, composed by a beautiful photo gallery can help the user appreciate the beauty of manufacturer XXX design

can somebody help me rephrase it?

Comment: Most people (though not all, I've discovered here on ELU) would want an apostrophe after _riders_. But I'm afraid the request for optimal style is off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The beauty of XXX's motorcycle design

Is an appropriate phrase. The problem is your sentence is expressing an overwhelming amount of detail when it is clearly intended to provide a brief introduction to the subject matter. Take out what you think is the least important descriptor and add it in another sentence.

For example:

> An immersive, photo-driven experience showcasing the beauty of XXX's motorcycle design. Supported by the stories of real riders, ...

Comment: love it. thank you. this is very interesting answer